# How do I use a completionBlock in swift?

Tags: closures, swift, completion-block

I'm trying to utilize swift's SKStoreProductViewController, but am getting errors with my syntax, specifically with my completion block.

Here is my code:

```
let storeViewController:SKStoreProductViewController = SKStoreProductViewController();
storeViewController.delegate = self;

var productparameters = [SKStoreProductParameterITunesItemIdentifier:someitunesid];

storeViewController.loadProductWithParameters(productparameters,
    (success: Bool!, error: NSError!) -> Void in
        if success {
    self.presentViewController(storeViewController, animated: true, completion: nil);
        } else {
        NSLog("%@", error)
    }
  )
```

After running this I get an `expected "," separator` error between the `error:NSError!),-> Void`

This doesn't make sense to me as the apple docs call for:

```
func loadProductWithParameters(_ parameters: [NSObject : AnyObject]!,
           completionBlock block: ((Bool, NSError!) -> Void)!)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're 99% there, you just need braces around your block to have the correct closure syntax:

```
storeViewController.loadProductWithParameters(productparameters, { (success: Bool!, error: NSError!) -> Void in
    if success {
        self.presentViewController(storeViewController, animated: true, completion: nil);
    } else {
        NSLog("%@", error)
    }
})
```

You can read [more about closures in Apple's documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Closures.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH11-XID_117).